# Command line arguments to Java applications in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans, arguments

I'm new to Netbeans. I need to pass some command line arguments to some Java files, but "Run file" doesn't let me do it.

I don't see the "Run with arguments" plugin from the list of available plugins.

I have no "arguments" text input in project properties -> run.

How can I pass command line arguments to java files?

[[image: project properties -> run]]

Comment: You are going to run a webapp, and the webapp can not pass the arguments to run like the jar (because the webapp does not have the `main(String[] args)` like the jar). You might want to refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6187346/4039840).

Comment: my app is a webpp, but I have some classes which are "command line classes" and I'd like to execute them passing arguments

Comment: You want to call a command line to execute on your web app then you must write a function do that job and call to that function. There are not have an option for you to run web app with parameters. If this is a dynamic parameters you can create a function with a UI control to call and pass your params, if this is a non-dynamic then config params in properties file of config.xml like the like I have proposed

Comment: I don't want to execute a web app with parameters, the whole project is a web app, but it also contains singles classes that are simple "command line classes" which accept parameters, and I want to pass arguments to them

Comment: I already proposed the solution for you. I'm sure that you can not "pass arguments to command line classes" in a web app like what you have descrip above.

Comment: You proposed to read the parameters through getServletContext(), but the "command line classes" aren't servlet, so how should I read the parameters from there? I was thinking to use another approach, changing the nature of the project, i.e. setting it not as a web app but as a simple project, do you know how could I do this?

Comment: You don't have to change the type of project, you can save the value into a file (recommend .properties file) then read it when you need to call your "command line classes". Another approach for you is [spring boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/), I don't really good about it but I know that it have a main method like a normal java project